# Why $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(5n^3-3n^2+7)(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}(n+1)^2} =5e$?

Tags: limits

I have a small exercise and I don’t know who to get the result.

> The exercise is: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(5n^3-3n^2+7)(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}(n+1)^2} $$

I did following transformations:
$$
\frac{(5n^3-3n^2+7)(n+1)^{n-2}}{n^{n+1}} \\
(5n^{2-n}-3n^{1-n}+7^{-1-n})(n+1)^{n-2} \\
(\frac{5}{n^{-2+n}} - \frac{3}{n^{-1+n}} + \frac{7}{n^{1+n}})(n+1)^{n-2}
$$

But none of them helped me to see the result.
It would be great if someone could explain it to me.

**Edit**

@adrian-barquero
Ok. Fist you factories $^n$ and get
$$
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e \\
$$

In the other fraction I could extend with $n^3$
$$
\frac{5n^3-3n^2+7}{n(n + 1)^2} = \frac{n^3(5 - \frac{3n^2}{n^3} + \frac{7}{n^3})}{n^3(1 + \frac{2n^2}{n^3} + \frac{n}{n^3})} = 5
$$

Comment: Do you know $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+(1/n))^n$? It might comes in handy....

Comment: The answer is not $5$.

Comment: probably 5e ...

Comment: [check this out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\lim_{n+\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{%285n^3-3n^2%2B7%29%28n%2B1%29^n}{n^{n%2B1}%28n%2B1%29^2})

Comment: Yes, Wolframalpha told me too :) I changed my **Edit**.

Comment: What does "Fist you factories ${}^n$" mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend rearranging as

$$
\frac{(5n^3-3n^2+7)(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}(n+1)^2} = \frac{5n^3-3n^2+7}{n(n + 1)^2}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} = \frac{5n^3-3n^2+7}{n(n + 1)^2} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n}  \right )^n
$$

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Pleas see my **Edit**. Does I understand it correctly? Greetz.

Comment: @hofmeister Yes, your edit seems fine. Just be careful that you should add limits in front of your expressions. And check the last limit you wrote, the answer should be $5$, but you wrote $5e$ instead, although I'm sure that was just a typo.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will keep in my mind. Wish a nice day.